# Win8.1 desktop font changed

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, fonts

I turn my computer on and I've noticed that Win8.1 font changed except Start window. I've tried `Control Panel->Appearance and Personalization->Fonts->Font settings->Restore default font settings` and checked default fonts in `Run->Regedit->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->Software->Windows NT->CurrentVersion->FontSubstitutes`.

What I should do that in Desktop and in other parts of Win 8.1 font would be normal

[image: Desktop view]

[image: Start view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I somehow replaced system fonts. I downloaded Win8.1 fonts ant put them into `C:\Windows\Fonts` folder. [Win8.1 fonts and more details here.](http://woshub.com/how-to-restore-default-fonts-in-windows-8-1/)